# SQL Aggregation by Hour

Tags: sqlite, aggregate

I have an SQLite database (version 3.31.1) for my electricity usage and generation. It has over 100,000 rows, and about 600 days. The "StartTime" field contains the start time of the bucket for the count of Units.

Unfortunately, the start time is **not always on the 15 minute boundary**. Some of the hours are divided into 4 (15 minute buckets), sometimes divided into 6 (10 minute buckets), and sometimes into 2 (30 minute buckets).

I'm using matplotlib to generate some charts. https://www.glasson.org/solar/selenium_chrome/index.php
I built some charts that show the time-of-day stats, but because the buckets are of variable size, the charts are "spikey".

I want to aggregate the "Unit" in to hourly buckets, but my SQL skills are too poor to figure it out.

To generate one of the linked charts, the SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
  Time AS TME,
  ROUND(AVG(ImportPeak),1)  AS IPE,
  ROUND(AVG(ImportOPeak),1) AS IOP,
  ROUND(AVG(ImportSh),1)    AS ISH,
  ROUND(AVG(Exported),1)    AS EXP
  FROM ActewData
  WHERE Date > 20210903
  GROUP BY TME
```

A sample of a few rows of data looks like this -

```
sqlite> select * from ActewData limit 6; 
Date|Time|Rate|Generated|Exported|PeakPwr|PeakTm|Condition|MinTemp|MaxTemp|Comments|ImportPeak|ImportOPeak|ImportSh|ImportShHi|Consumption|ExportPeak|ExportOPeak|ExportSh|ExportShHi
20220505|23:55|Solar||0|||||||0|0|0||||||
20220505|23:55|Offpeak||0|||||||0|38|0|||||| 
20220505|23:50|Solar||0|||||||0|0|0|||||| 
20220505|23:50|Offpeak||0|||||||0|24|0|||||| 
20220505|23:45|Solar||0|||||||0|0|0|||||| 
20220505|23:45|Offpeak||0|||||||0|23|0|||||| 
sqlite>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. It would be easy if you provide some sample data using a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27) and the desired result.

Comment: 3.31.1sqlite> select * from ActewData limit 100;
Date|Time|Rate|Generated|Exported|PeakPwr|PeakTm|Condition|MinTemp|MaxTemp|Comments|ImportPeak|ImportOPeak|ImportSh|ImportShHi|Consumption|ExportPeak|ExportOPeak|ExportSh|ExportShHi
20220505|23:55|Solar||0|||||||0|0|0||||||
20220505|23:55|Offpeak||0|||||||0|38|0||||||
20220505|23:50|Solar||0|||||||0|0|0||||||
20220505|23:50|Offpeak||0|||||||0|24|0||||||
20220505|23:45|Solar||0|||||||0|0|0||||||
20220505|23:45|Offpeak||0|||||||0|23|0||||||
sqlite>

Comment: Please, [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/311685/edit) the question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strftime() function to extract the hour from Time column.

```
SELECT
Date,
strftime('%H', Time) AS TME,
ROUND(AVG(ImportPeak),1)  AS IPE,
ROUND(AVG(ImportOPeak),1) AS IOP,
ROUND(AVG(ImportSh),1)    AS ISH,
ROUND(AVG(Exported),1)    AS EXP
FROM ActewData
WHERE Date > 20210903
GROUP BY Date, strftime('%H', Time)
```